# setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (SequencerActivity) back.setOnClickListener(this);

Tags: android

I want to display an image on button click, but I have three errors in my code. What's wrong?

1. ```
   class name "SequencerActivity"
   ```

   The type SequencerActivity must implement the inherited abstract method `DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)`.
2. ```
   next.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```

   The method `setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)` in the type View is not applicable for the arguments `(SequencerActivity)`.
3. ```
   onClick(View v)
   ```

The method `onClick(View)` of type `SequencerActivity` must override or implement a supertype method.

Here's the code giving those errors:

```
public class SequencerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
private int imageCounter = 0;
private ImageView imageLoader;

private int[] imageList = {R.drawable.f03, R.drawable.f04, R.drawable.f05, R.drawable.f06};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    setContentView(R.layout.main);//this one is the common parent layout for all image views
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/

    //int image1 = R.drawable.image_w_lbl_0;

    imageLoader = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageLoader);
    //imageLoader.setImageResource(image1);

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setEnabled(false);
    //show the default image
    this.loadImage(imageList[imageCounter]);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    int imagePath = 0;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.next:
        Log.i("Tag","tag");
        if(imageCounter < imageList.length)
        {
            imageCounter++;
            imagePath = imageList[imageCounter];
            if (imageCounter==(imageList.length)-1)
            {
                { 
                    ImageButton next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next); 
                    next.setEnabled(false); 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ImageButton back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back); 
                back.setEnabled(true); 
            }
        }
        break;
    case R.id.back:
        if(imageCounter > 0)
        {
            imageCounter--;
            imagePath = imageList[imageCounter];
            if (imageCounter==0) 
            { 
                ImageButton back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back); 
                back.setEnabled(false); 
            }
            else
            {
                ImageButton next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next); 
                next.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    this.loadImage(imagePath);

}

private void loadImage(int imagePath)
{
    imageLoader.setImageResource(imagePath);

}

}
```

Comment: mark answered please. darune is totally correct (in my case at least)

Answer (score 41):

The `OnClickListener` that you implement is not correct, 
try to implement View.OnClickListener and not DialogInterface.OnClickListener.

You can see that in your import

`import View.OnClickListener`

instead of

`import DialogInterface.OnClickListener`

Answer (score 14):

you need to import `import android.view.View.OnClickListener;`

So your code look like

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
  // Your oncreate() and rest of all code
}
// you should have method as below
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(v.getId() == R.id.editText1) // just for instance 
    {
        .. your onclick handle code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Still you are not able to resolve the error type `import View.OnClickListener;` then move the cursor on the View in `import View.OnClickListener;` It will open up pop-up then choose the Organize imports option.

Use simply `import View.OnClickListener;` at the top.

Answer (score 3):

The `OnClickListener` you're implementing is the wrong one. It says it's `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`, while you probably want `View.OnClickListener`. You can correct that in the corresponding `import` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just do only One thing. Use "import android.view.View.OnClickListener" statement at the top of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing

remove **import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;** 
and import
**android.View.View.OnClickListener**

this will solve the problem

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

Implement View.view.onClickListener

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.