# sqlite database for gps location

Tags: android, sql

I am new at android.  I followed tutorials from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JyC_xv20yE
There is no error in program. But emulator gives "*the application stopped unexpectedly*"

log file as

```
04-11 19:50:14.295: D/AndroidRuntime(338): Shutting down VM
04-11 19:50:14.295: W/dalvikvm(338): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sql/com.sql.SQLiteExample}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sql.SQLiteExample
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.sql.SQLiteExample.onCreate(SQLiteExample.java:28)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-11 19:50:14.315: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  ... 11 more
04-11 19:55:14.435: I/Process(338): Sending signal. PID: 338 SIG: 9
04-11 20:02:38.005: W/dalvikvm(367): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sql/com.sql.SQLiteExample}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sql.SQLiteExample
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sql.SQLiteExample
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.sql.SQLiteExample.onCreate(SQLiteExample.java:28)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  ... 11 more
04-11 20:07:38.165: I/Process(367): Sending signal. PID: 367 SIG: 9
```

SQLiteexample.java as

```
package com.sql;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SQLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Button sqlUpdate,sqlView;
    EditText sqllocation,sqllongi,sqllati;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sqliteexample);
        sqlUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsqlupdate);
        sqlView = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bsqlopenview);
        sqllongi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.longi);
        sqllati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lati);
        sqllocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.location1);
        sqlView.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
        sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);

    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0.getId())
        {
        case R.id.bsqlupdate:
            boolean wrk=true;
            try{
            String location = sqllocation.getText().toString();
            String longi = sqllongi.getText().toString();
            String lati = sqllongi.getText().toString();
            Cornte entry = new Cornte(this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(location , longi, lati);

            entry.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                wrk= false;
                String error=e.toString();
                Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("NO!!!");
                TextView tv =new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show(); 

            }finally{
                if(wrk)
                {
                    Dialog d=new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("YUP!!!");
                    TextView tv =new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("SUCCESS");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bsqlopenview:
            Intent i =new Intent("com.sql.SQLVIEW");
            startActivity(i);

            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: instead of your code Add Error Code First.

Comment: Check your logcat where the exception is

Comment: @Abhi how to do dat? i m amateur..

Comment: In menu bar: Window>show view>logcat.. run the application you can see the log

Comment: Check your logcat from DDMS=> Log-cat => copy the error log from there and paste here.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sql.SQLiteExample
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.sql.SQLiteExample.onCreate(SQLiteExample.java:28) , it suggest error is in 28th line

Comment: @AviKumarManku abhi dev please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186337/nullpointer-exception-proximity-alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in:

```
sqlView.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
```

You can see it in your logcat:

```
04-11 20:02:38.045: E/AndroidRuntime(367):  at com.sql.SQLiteExample.onCreate(SQLiteExample.java:28)
```

I'll explain, first try learning to use the logcat, mostly you should just start at the bottom of the error and search for the lines with your namespace (in this case com.sql.SQLiteExample), now you can see what method made your app crash, in this example: 'onCreate' but most important is the file + line number where the error occured!

ClassCastException means that you want to put an Object into an Object it isn't...
School example you got BaseObjects 'Animal' which has some ChildObjects 'Dogg' & 'Cat' but now you are trying to do the following:

```
Apple apple = giveMeThatApple();
Animal a = apple;
```

Well that won't work since that 'apple' has nothing to do with the Class 'Animal'... I hope you understand...

Comment: please help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186337/nullpointer-exception-proximity-alert

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution.. the error is due to wrong import of import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener; instead of import View.OnClickListener
[setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (SequencerActivity) back.setOnClickListener(this);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071799/setonclicklistenerview-onclicklistener-in-the-type-view-is-not-applicable-for)