# NullPointerException proximity alert

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-pendingintent, proximity

I am creating an application, which tracks the users location using GPS, stores the longitude and latitude in a SQLite database and adds proximity alerts.
reference - http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html

ERROR Message `java.lang.NullPointerException`
LogCat:

```
04-19 08:14:42.617: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(585): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-19 08:18:18.477: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(585): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-19 08:18:26.717: D/dalvikvm(585): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3939 objects / 240736 bytes in 1956ms
04-19 08:18:37.947: W/KeyCharacterMap(636): No keyboard for id 0
04-19 08:18:37.947: W/KeyCharacterMap(636): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-19 08:18:46.638: D/AndroidRuntime(636): Shutting down VM
04-19 08:18:46.638: W/dalvikvm(636): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.sql.SQLiteExample.saveProximityAlertPoint(SQLiteExample.java:157)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.sql.SQLiteExample.onClick(SQLiteExample.java:107)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-19 08:18:46.677: E/AndroidRuntime(636):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error code lines:

```
saveProximityAlertPoint(location1,longi, lati);
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: At what point it happens? if you don't have a log add debug prints and find out. IT will be easier for all of us.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet please see log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the member `locationManager` is not initialized where you call `saveProximityAlertPoint()` or the initialisation of `locationManager` failed.