# Android button click doesn't work and editing textbox with it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm really new in coding for Android, just started to learn. I have some image buttons to change values displayed in textboxes and I don't know how to do this. I tried some tests for buttons but I have some errors which I can't repair.

Message from eclipse is:

The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

and

The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

for setOnClickListener and OnClickListener

I looked at this thread but still I don't know what to do

[setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (SequencerActivity) back.setOnClickListener(this);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071799/setonclicklistenerview-onclicklistener-in-the-type-view-is-not-applicable-for)

Except that, I want to change the Medium text fields with the buttons. Perhaps by the declared integers.

Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
int vs,vh,ws,wh,wth,wts;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
    protected void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ApplicationContext(), "Om nom nom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}
```

xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#012e53"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
tools:context="pl.tmalachowski.truewindcalc.MainActivity" >

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:textColor="#bdc3c7" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/ves"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/podst" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView10"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/rel"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/podst" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="62dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/ves1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/podst" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="77dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/ves2"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/podst" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/rel1"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/podst" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/rel2"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="@color/podst" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

Declare like this ImageButton b1; instead of Button b1;
then change to like this following code

```
b1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(ApplicationContext(), "Om nom nom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Still the same with setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: Are you using ImageButton or Button in your xml layout?

Comment: I'm using ImageButtons

Comment: Still occuring The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using your `onClickListener` wrong.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Om nom nom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Please try this usage. Hope it helps

Comment: Now the app is crashing after running.